# AWS S3 List Objects Inconsistency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list the objects with a given prefix using the AWS S3 cli. However, it sometimes returns different results for seemingly identical folder structures.

Ok so here is command #1

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket b --prefix 38d2f2e0-8091-11e9-aaa9-03fd73386354/raw 

38d2f2e0-8091-11e9-aaa9-03fd73386354/raw/Pogonocherus_hispidus_Max.1001.png     
38d2f2e0-8091-11e9-aaa9-03fd73386354/raw/Pogonocherus_hispidus_Max.mtl  
38d2f2e0-8091-11e9-aaa9-03fd73386354/raw/Pogonocherus_hispidus_Max.obj
```

and here #2

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket b --prefix 5d5c3abe-1a95-4e92-a03d-11fbf37d7851/raw 

5d5c3abe-1a95-4e92-a03d-11fbf37d7851/raw/
5d5c3abe-1a95-4e92-a03d-11fbf37d7851/raw/Pogonocherus_hispidus_Max.1001.png    
5d5c3abe-1a95-4e92-a03d-11fbf37d7851/raw/Pogonocherus_hispidus_Max.mtl
5d5c3abe-1a95-4e92-a03d-11fbf37d7851/raw/Pogonocherus_hispidus_Max.obj
```

I have no idea why it's doing that. Ideally, i want the output to always look like #1.

What's going on here?

Comment: you could run the results through grep exclude everything ending in `/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the two listings is the presence in the second list of a `raw/` subfolder object. With S3, it's not necessary to create a folder before writing a object to that folder. And, when you create an object such as `folder1/folder2/image.jpg`, S3 does not create the `folder1/folder2/` structure; it simply writes the object.

So, some process that you are using is deliberately creating an object at `5d5c3abe-1a95-4e92-a03d-11fbf37d7851/raw/` to represent the `raw/` subfolder. There's no need to create this folder typically but some clients do. As you can see, things work just fine in the first example without the `raw/` subfolder.

So, see if you can identify some difference in the way you are populating S3 that might cause the `uuid/raw/` subfolder to be created. One common cause is that someone used the AWS S3 Console to [create a folder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html#create-folder).

Comment: You're right! Seems like someone created one of the folders by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for an entire night, along with more than 1000 files and I also wanted to just get the number of files under a subfolder but it was also returning one extra file in the content that was the subfolder itself,

After searching about it I found that this is how s3 works but I had a scenario where I unloaded the data from redshift in the following directory

```
s3://bucket_name/subfolder/<10 number of files>
```

and when I used

```
paginator.paginate(Bucket=price_signal_bucket_name,Prefix=new_files_folder_path+"/")
```

it would only return the 10 files, but when I created the folder on the s3 bucket itself then it would also return the subfolder and the 10 files i.e 11 entries in total

Conclusion

1. If the whole folder is uploaded to s3 then listing the only returns the files under prefix
2. But if the fodler was created on the s3 bucket itself then listing it using boto3 client will also return the subfolder and the files